# Find Abandoned Searches from Customer Activities, SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, where-clause

In a trading platform, users have three different actions: `LOGIN`, `SEARCH`, `ORDER`.

Abandoned `SEARCH` action is defined as: customers `LOGIN` then do some `SEARCH` and do not `ORDER` before next `LOGIN`.
Now I have a table: `action_table`, recording `customer_id`, `action`, `request_time`.

I want to know how to find all abandoned SEARCH actions via SQL?

---

Updated:
Here is a brief example:

```
CREATE TABLE action_table(
   customer_id  VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
  ,action       VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL
  ,request_time DATE  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO action_table(customer_id,action,request_time) 
VALUES 
('A','LOGIN','2023-05-01'),
('A','SEARCH','2023-05-02'),
('A','SEARCH','2023-05-03'),
('A','ORDER','2023-05-04'),
('B','LOGIN','2023-05-01'),
('B','SEARCH','2023-05-02'),
('B','SEARCH','2023-05-03'),
('B','LOGIN','2023-05-04'),
('B','SEARCH','2023-05-05')
```

| customer_id | action | request_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | LOGIN | 2023-05-01 |
| A | SEARCH | 2023-05-02 |
| A | SEARCH | 2023-05-03 |
| A | ORDER | 2023-05-04 |
| B | LOGIN | 2023-05-01 |
| B | SEARCH | 2023-05-02 |
| B | SEARCH | 2023-05-03 |
| B | LOGIN | 2023-05-04 |
| B | SEARCH | 2023-05-05 |

In this case, **NO** abandoned SEARCH for A and **3** abandoned SEARCH for B.

Here is my code:

```
select customer_id, count(1)
from action_table c1
left join 
(
  select customer_id, action, request_time 
  from action_table
  where action = 'LOGIN'
) c2
  on c1.customer_id = c2.customer_id
  and c2.request_time > c1.request_time
left join 
(
  select customer_id, action, request_time 
  from action_table
  where action = 'ORDER'
) c3
  on c1.customer_id = c3.customer_id
  and c3.request_time > c1.request_time
  and c3.request_time < c2.request_time
where c1.action = 'SEARCH'
  and c2.customer_id IS NOT NULL
  and c3.customer_id IS NULL
group by 1
```

It is redundant and does not seem to work well :(

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: updated. add a demo here and post my code @jarlh

Comment: Can you also _specify_ the expected result? (Same format as the sample table data.)

Comment: Column `request_time` data type? (Looks more like a date than a time.)

Comment: Would LOGIN, SEARCH, SEARCH, SEARCH, LOGIN be 1 abandoned search, or 3?

Comment: @jarlh sry for late. Expected result: In this case, NO abandoned SEARCH for A and 2 abandoned SEARCH for B. `request_time` is `date` for sure.
For your case 'LOGIN, SEARCH, SEARCH, SEARCH, LOGIN' would be taken as 3abandoned search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution. This is not an optimal one but still works.

The basic approach is to find the most recent `LOGIN` action after each `SEARCH`. Then check if `ORDER` exists between search time and most recent login time. Two subqueries are used :(

```sql
SELECT *
FROM action_table AS a
WHERE a.action = 'SEARCH'
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM action_table
    WHERE customer_id = a.customer_id
      AND action = 'ORDER'
      AND request_time > a.request_time
      AND request_time < (
        SELECT MIN(request_time)
        FROM action_table
        WHERE customer_id = a.customer_id
          AND action = 'LOGIN'
          AND request_time > a.request_time
      )
);
```

Answer (score 3):

One option uses `LEAD`; the idea is to check the two following actions of each login event to identify abandonned searches:

```
select customer_id, count(*) cnt_abandonned_search
from (
    select a.*, 
        lead(action, 1) over(partition by customer_id order by request_time) lead_action_1,
        lead(action, 2) over(partition by customer_id order by request_time) lead_action_2
    from action_table a
) a
where action = 'LOGIN'                         -- a LOGIN action...
  and lead_action_1 = 'SEARCH'                 -- ... followed by a SEARCH
  and lead_action_2 is distinct from 'ORDER'   -- ... but not followed by an ORDER
group by customer_id
```

---

If you wanted to focus on searches, and get the entire record of each abandoned search, we can use the same logic but with `lead` and `lag`:

```
select *
from (
    select a.*, 
        lag (action) over(partition by customer_id order by request_time) lag_action,
        lead(action) over(partition by customer_id order by request_time) lead_action
    from action_table a
) a
where action = 'SEARCH'                    -- a SEARCH action...
  and lag_action = 'LOGIN'                 -- ... preceded by a LOGIN
  and lead_action is distinct from 'ORDER' -- ... but not followed by an ORDER
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7ePQzzz2)**

Comment: tks! But this code does not take `B SEARCH 2023-5-04` in the sample data as abandoned search.

Comment: It is a good way to count abandoned search. What if I want to know the `request time` of each abandoned search? -- I want to extract lines of abandoned searches.

Comment: @Cino: yes, this does identify the two abandonned searches in your example data. I updated my answer to include another query, that gives the detail of each abandoned search - and added a DB Fiddle.

Comment: tks for DB Fiddle! This code does identify 2 abandoned search actions. But what if B did several searches before next login? In the updated sample data, for A: A searched twice and placed order, thus no abandoned search will be counted; for B: B searched twice and 'login', thus 2 abandoned searches will be counted. Is it possible to sovle this with `lead` and `lag`?